# (async) JSON RPC API performance optimization

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous, json-rpc, pg-promise

I have to make a JSON RPC API that will have to support a big traffic and manage a postgreSQL database.
To do it I chose 'http' for the server and [pg-promise](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/index.html) for the database.
My problem is that I have some difficulty understanding and using the promises and async/wait, so I'm not sure I did it correctly

I put some code below

#### What I did

1. ./server/server.js create an http server with `requestHandler()` as request handler. It does some checks and then calls `async requestProcessor()` to execute the method
2. The methods are defined in the repos (here a transaction in devices.js) as `async` and in my example below use `await` to wait for the required results

#### Some questions :

1. I have to define as `async` only the methods that should use `await` ?
2. In my SystemRepository, do I need to define 'InsertOneSystem' as `async` ?
3. How can I do a simple test script to test the load ? Like requests per second, ... ?

Thanks in advance !

#### A bit of code

**server.js**

```js
const http = require('http');
const Database = require('../db');

const path = '/api/v1', port = 9000;
const methods = Database.methods;

/* hidden for brevity */

function sendResponse(res, response) {
  if (response) {
    const responseStr = JSON.stringify(response);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', responseStr.length);
    res.write(responseStr);
  } else {
    /* hidden for brevity */
  }
  res.end();
}

const requestHandler = (req, res) => {
  /* some checks, hidden for brevity */

  const body = [];
  req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', () => {
    const bodyStr = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

    // parse body en JSON
    let request = JSON.parse(bodyStr);

    requestProcessor(request).then((response) => {
      sendResponse(res, response);
    });
  });
}

async function requestProcessor(request) {
  let response = {
    id: request.id,
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
  };

  try {
    response.result = await Promise.resolve(methods[request.method](request.params));
  } catch (err) {
    /* hidden for brevity */
  }

  return response;
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);
server.listen(port, (err) => { /* hidden for brevity */ });
```

**devices.js**

```js
'use strict';

/* hidden for brevity */

async function InsertOne(params) {
  return Database.tx('Insert-New-Device', async function(transaction) {
    let system = null, disks = null, cpus = null;

    const query = pgp.helpers.insert(params.data.device, Collections.insert) + " RETURNING *";
    let device = await transaction.one(query);

    // if a system is present, insert with diviceId and return
    if(params.data.system) {
      params.data.system.deviceid = device.deviceid;
      system = transaction.systems.InsertOne(params);
    }

    // same as system
    if(params.data.disks) {
      params.data.disks.deviceid = device.deviceid;
      disks = transaction.disks.InsertOne(params);
    }

    // same as system
    if(params.data.cpus) {
      params.data.cpus.deviceid = device.deviceid;
      cpus = transaction.cpus.InsertOne(params);
    }

    return {
      device: device,
      system: await system,
      disks: await disks,
      cpus: await cpus
    }
  })
  .then(data => {
    return data;
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.log(ex)
    throw new Error(ex);
  });
}

/* hidden for brevity */

const DevicesRepository = {
  InsertOne: InsertOne
};

module.exports = (db, pgpLib) => {
  /* hidden for brevity */
  return DevicesRepository;
}
```

**systems.js**

```js
'use strict';

/* hidden for brevity */

async function InsertOneSystem(params) {
  var system = params.data.system;
  system.archid=2;
  system.distributionid=3;

  var query = pgp.helpers.insert(system, Collections.insert);
  if(params.return) query += " RETURNING *";

  return Database.one(query)
          .then(data => {
            return data;
          })
          .catch(ex => {
            throw new Error(ex);
          });
}

/* hidden for brevity */

const SystemsRepository = {
  InsertOne: InsertOneSystem
};

module.exports = (db, pgpLib) => {
/* hidden for brevity */

  return SystemsRepository;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing `await` on three database calls - `transaction.systems.InsertOne`, plus the two below it. Oh wait, you are using `await` on the variables below, that's a bit unusual, LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to define as `async` only the methods that should use await ?

Have to - yes. But you should use `async` on all methods that return a promise, it's just a nice coding style, especially in TypeScript.

> In my `SystemRepository`, do I need to define `InsertOneSystem` as async ?

You don't have to, but the same as above, it's a good coding style ;)

> How can I do a simple test script to test the load ? Like requests per second, ... ?

I'm not answering that right now, as it is a whole separate area that deserves a separate question. You should investigate it yourself, how to test HTTP services load.

A little code improving, as you have plenty of redundancies:

```
async function InsertOne(params) {
  return Database.tx('Insert-New-Device', async t => {
    let system = null, disks = null, cpus = null;

    const query = pgp.helpers.insert(params.data.device, Collections.insert) + " RETURNING *";
    let device = await t.one(query);

    // if a system is present, insert with diviceId and return
    if(params.data.system) {
      params.data.system.deviceid = device.deviceid;
      system = await t.systems.InsertOne(params);
    }

    // same as system
    if(params.data.disks) {
      params.data.disks.deviceid = device.deviceid;
      disks = await t.disks.InsertOne(params);
    }

    // same as system
    if(params.data.cpus) {
      params.data.cpus.deviceid = device.deviceid;
      cpus = await t.cpus.InsertOne(params);
    }

    return {device, system, disks, cpus};
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.log(ex); // it is better use "pg-monitor", or handle events globally
    throw ex;
  });
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `await` "blocks" the code as a synchronous funtion right ?
Putting `await` as I did does not allow pg-promise to do all the insertions asynchronously and return the object when they are all done?

Comment: @Firlfire In general asynchronous logic there would be a difference. But in this case you are executing it all against the same physical IO port, so the result of your code and mine will be the same.